# Most efficient library to diagonalize exactly large hermitian or unitary matrices

Tags: c++, eigensystem, eigenvalues, computational-physics, mathematica

I am working on a physics problem which requires obtaining the exact eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Hermitian and Unitary matrices numerically. Naturally I would like to ask the experts what are the most efficient libraries to diagonalize the referred matrices. In particular, I would like to diagonalize efficiently matrices of size 12870*12870. I have been using Mathematica for convenience, but I am open to use any language you might suggest. I also have access to a HPC cluster in which the diagonalization of a unitary matrix of size 12870*12870 takes around 7000 seconds in Mathematica using 12 cores. Can this time be improved? Note: The matrices are numeric (not symbolic).

To be more precise, I diagonalized a random Hermitian matrix and a random Unitary matrix of size 12870 on the cluster using Mathematica. Here is the code I used:

```
With[{mat = RandomReal[1, 12870 {1, 1}]}, AbsoluteTiming[{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[mat+Transpose[mat]];]] 

With[{matu = Transpose[vecs].(Exp[I*vals]*Conjugate[vecs])}, AbsoluteTiming[Eigensystem[matu];]]
```

The results were:

```
In[1]:= Out[1]= {265.369827, Null} 
In[2]:= Out[2]= {7042.662152, Null}
```

So the unitary matrix diagonalization takes a lot more time. Can this be improved using other languages?

Comment: Something's wrong with the timings you cite.  If you have a numerical matrix of that size, finding all eigenvalues with Mathematica should not take more than 5-10 minutes on a laptop.  Post the specific Mathematica code you used.

Comment: Make sure that your matrix contains only machine precision floating point numbers.

Comment: @Szabolcs I acted with N function on the unitary matrix before applying Eigensystem to it. Are you sure it should take 5-10 minutes? Have you tried an example? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with `Eigenvalues`.  `Eigensystem` would take a little longer, see the extended comment I wrote in an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.  I'll get back to this later today.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to diagonalize significantly larger matrices on large HPC clusters, I would look at [Elemental](http://libelemental.org/), which is a state-of-the-art distributed dense linear algebra library. It's a better alternative than other libraries out there (e.g., ScaLAPACK, PLAPACK), and builds upon BLAS and LAPACK implementations.

Comment: This library seems to be aimed at distributed memory computation.  If the whole matrix fits in memory, how would its performance compare to e.g. the MKL running on a shared memory system?  I'm asking because the OP's matrix likely fits in memory (about 1.3 GB for one matrix), and I always thought that switching to C from MATLAB/Mathematica will not help at all when the whole computation is a *single* function call to a linear algebra operation with a large matrix.  The bottleneck is the MKL or other LAPACK implementation anyway, not the language it's being calling from.

Comment: @Szabolcs: It is aimed at distributed memory computation, and was mainly a response to the answer of coincoin. If the matrix fits in memory, and you run it in serial, I would think that yes, LAPACK would be the bottleneck, not the language used to call it. You could still run this computation in parallel on an architecture like BG/P and get a speedup relative to a serial implementation; see the case studies in http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2427023.2427030, which include an eigendecomposition of a 10,000 by 10,000 matrix on 8192 cores.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a HPC cluster and you want to work on matrix of larger size (12k^2 order is not much), I would suggest to use [Lapack routines](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node48.html). 
This is a base/reference in numerical linear algebra available in Fortran or C.

Comment: Could you write a code example for reference, where you generate a random unitary matrix U( U=exp(i*H), where H is a random Hermitian matrix) and diagonalize it using Lapack in C++? How much time only in diagonalization does it take  for a matrix of size 12870?

Comment: Mathematica, like all other similar software (MATLAB, etc.) also uses LAPACK (actually it uses the MKL).  For these types of problems (large matrices, a single call to eigenvalue computation) there is typically no advantage to using C or Fortran.  The limiting factor is going to be the LAPACK implementation anyway.

Comment: I thought there was still an overhead when using these softwares. And do these softwares implement parallel algorithms for a multi core environment since the original lapack does not provide that. And if he uses a HPC cluster maybe he may needsto get a code for production or Mathematica provides tools when using parallel architectures ?